# Gluon mobile VideoService not working for media files stored locally on android device?

Tags: android, gluon-mobile

In my application I'd like to play videos from URL or files stored locally on the android device using Gluon-mobile VideoService.
This works fine for URLs, but (in my environment) it does not work for files stored on the android device, 
e.g. `/sdcard/DCIM/tmp/1834.mp4.`

The LogCat shows

```
V/MediaPlayerService(2431): Create new media retriever from pid 10868
W/AndroidVideoService(10868): Invalid video file: /sdcard/DCIM/tmp/1834.mp4
V/MediaPlayer(10868): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
```

I can play the file in that location with the standalone Android Video-Player.

I also tried to copy the file programmatically to the directories delivered by

- `StorageService.getPublicStorage("Movies")` (->
  `/storage/emulated/0/Movies`) or
- `StorageService.getPrivateStorage()` (-> `/data/user/0/mypackage/files`)

plus "/tmp/" + "1834.mp4"

and play it via the application from there, but the LogCat message again shows

```
W/AndroidVideoService(...): Invalid video file ...
```

The javadoc of [VideoService.getPlaylist()](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.1/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/VideoService.html#getPlaylist--) says

> The media files (video and audio) can either be a valid URL **or they
>   can be provided in the resources folder**.

**So is it not possible to play media files stored locally on android device ?**

Here are the relevant parts of my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.1'
    // ...
}
// ...
jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'video' 
    }
// ...
}
```

My phone has Android 8.1.

**Added source code for testing purposes:**

```
int i = 0;
try {
    File privateAppStorage = Services.get(StorageService.class)
              .flatMap(StorageService::getPrivateStorage)
              .orElseThrow(() -> new FileNotFoundException("Could not access private storage."));
    String outputfilename = privateAppStorage + "/1834.mp4";

    if(i == 0) { // to skip copying set i != 0 on 2nd run
        // copy video
        File input = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/tmp/1834.mp4");
        int li = (int) input.length();
        byte[] bFile = new byte[li];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input);
        fis.read(bFile);
        fis.close();
        File output = new File(outputfilename);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
        fos.write(bFile);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        li = (int) output.length();

        /* test copying routine
        File testoutput = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/tmp/1834_2.mp4");
        FileOutputStream tfos = new FileOutputStream(testoutput);
        tfos.write(bFile);
        tfos.flush();
        tfos.close();
        li = (int) testoutput.length();
        */ // end test copying routine
    }
    // play video
    Optional<VideoService> service = Services.get(VideoService.class);
    if(service.isPresent()){
        VideoService videoService = service.get();
        videoService.setControlsVisible(true);
        videoService.setFullScreen(true);
        Status status = videoService.statusProperty().get();
        ObservableList<String> sl = videoService.getPlaylist();
        if(sl.size() > 0)
            sl.set(0, outputfilename);
        else
            videoService.getPlaylist().add(outputfilename);

        videoService.show(); 
    }
} catch ( IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Edit 2019-06-05**

More debug inormation regarding the DefaultVideoService internal copying process:

```
I/DefaultVideoService(10544): Copying video file: /data/user/0/mypackage/files/1834.mp4, from resources to /data/user/0/mypackage/files/assets/_data_user_0_com.hp_files_1834.mp4
I/DefaultVideoService(10544): Copying video file /data/user/0/mypackage/files/1834.mp4 finished with result: failed
I/AndroidVideoService(10544): Creating new MediaPlayer for /data/user/0/mypackage/files/1834.mp4
```

Debugging into `DefaultVideoService.copyFile(...)` I found that statement `DefaultVideoService.class.getResourceAsStream(pathIni)` returns null and thus DefaultVideoService internal copying fails.
Why it returns null, I do not know since I do not have the appropriate java.lang.Class source.

Comment: Have you tried copying the video from its current location to the private storage root, without extra folders, and then add it to the playlist just with its name?

Comment: @José Pereda: I placed 1834.mp4 directly under /data/user/0/mypackage/files and tried getPlaylist().add(s) with s ="1834.mp4" as well as "/data/user/0/mypackage/files/1834.mp4" both still resulted in W/AndroidVideoService(...): Invalid video file ...

Comment: I'd say you follow the java doc for the service: place a video that works, directly in `src/resources/video.mp4` of your project, and add it to the playlist (`video.getPlaylist().add("video.mp4");`). Then build the apk, deploy and test. If that works, try again with "1834.mp4" (download it from your Android device to your desktop machine). Again, if that works that means the video is a valid media file, and that the issue is related to copying it from its current location to the private storage of your app.

Comment: @José Pereda: I copied `1834.mp4` from the android device to my project under `src/resources`, deployed it and added it via `getPlaylist().add("1834.mp4")`. The video can be displayed!
To verify my copying routine I did the following;
(1) do a test copying to `/sdcard/DCIM/tmp/1834_2.mp4` and start this with Android Video-Player -> 1834_2.mp4 can be played
(2) to check if `FileOutputStream.flush` may be the cause, do a 2nd run with i != 0 witch skips copying (outputfile should already be  in privateAppStorage).
I will add my testing source code to my post.

Comment: After I enabled debuging for `com.gluonhq.charm.down` I saw a few more information regarding the `com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.DefaultVideoService` internal copying process. I will add this to my post (see Edit 2019-06-05)

Comment: Maybe you can try `StorageService.getPublicStorage("DCIM")`? Check if you get access to that folder in the first place, then look for the file and do the copy. Add some printouts so you can trace it from the logcat.

Comment: @José Pereda: No that doesn't work either (like getPublicStorage("Movies")). Meanwhile I think it is an intended behaviour that the Gluon mobile VideoService only plays videos via URL or deployed with the apk, though I can't think of a reason why to limit this. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that I found for my environment.
Lets say the file to be played is

```
String filename = "/sdcard/DCIM/tmp/1834.mp4";
```

Before calling

```
VideoService.getPlaylist.add(filename);
```

copy the file with the statements:

```
File privateAppStorage = Services.get(StorageService.class)
          .flatMap(StorageService::getPrivateStorage)
          .orElseThrow(() -> new FileNotFoundException("Could not access private storage."));
File assets = new File(privateAppStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "/assets");
boolean assets_exists = assets.exists();
if(!assets.exists())
{
    assets_exists = assets.mkdir();
}
if(assets_exists && assets.canWrite())
{
    File input = new File(filename);
    int li = (int) input.length();
    byte[] bFile = new byte[li];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input);
    fis.read(bFile);
    fis.close();

    File copiedToAssets = new File(assets.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename.replaceAll("/", "_"));
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(copiedToAssets);
    fos.write(bFile);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```

This bypasses `DefaultVideoService.class.getResourceAsStream(pathIni)` mentioned in my question and the video can be played.